# Xamarin Android/iOS иконка количества новых уведомлений

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, push-уведомления

Есть проект на Xamarin. Я организовал приём push-уведомлений приложением на Android. Мне нужно теперь, чтобы рядом с иконкой приложения на рабочем столе отображалось количество таких уведомлений (белая цифра в красном кружке), как например у приложения WhatsApp отображается кол-во новых сообщений, или при получении смс-сообщений. Как такое реализовать? Насколько я понял это штатная задача и решается средствами ОС из коробки? Интересует как для Android так и для iOS, в идеале еще и для WinPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы отображался баджик на иконке с цифрой в случае iOS, необходимо при отправке push уведомления добавить поле `badge` с цифрой, которая будет показана:

```
{
   "aps" : {
      "badge" : 1
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

В Android по-разному для разных версий андроида/оболочек, во многих случаях поддержки такого просто нет.